# Limit of function involving integrals

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit $$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{1}{\sin^{2}x}\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^x \sin^{-1}t dt$$

Should I use differentiation under the integral sign? Or should I simply take the derivative of $\sin^{-1}t$ and proceed?

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is the way to go.

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator by $x^2$.

Comment: We have $\arcsin t=t+O(t^2)$, indeed $t+O(t^3)$.

Comment: Is introduction of non-elementary functions really required? (I am not as advanced as you, so please if I do any mistake, please tell). @AndréNicolas

Comment: What I wrote is certainly not required, you gave a perfectly good argument. That $\arcsin t$ is $t+o(t)$ is, sort of, proved early in a calculus course, when one shows that $\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\sin s}{s}=1$. The versions I wrote down come from the Taylor expansion, so in typical courses come later. I use Taylor series reasoning to think about the approximate size of things. The advantage, for me, is that I feel I am in control, while L'Hospital's Rule feels mechanical.  That is partly illusory, Taylor expansion can also be thought of as mechanical.

Comment: Yeah! (y). I agree @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\int_{\frac x2}^x\sin^{-1}tdt=\int^x_0\sin^{-1}tdt-\int^{\frac x2}_0\sin^{-1}tdt$$
(It transforms the integral into an expression which can be differentiated by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.) 
And divide both the numerator and denominator by $x^2$. 
**Solution:**
So on differentiating, we get $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin^{-1}x-\frac12\sin^{-1}\frac x2}{2x}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac12.\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{1-\frac14}{2}=\boxed{\frac38}$$

Comment: In the second step of solution, shouldn't the derivative of $\sin^{-1}x$ be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$? How is it $\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$?

Comment: One minute, I'll edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: I got it, thank you! Was missing it by a bit

Comment: I liked the $3/8$ better. You are differentiating $\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(x/2)$. The derivative, I think, is $\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2/4}}$.  As an ad for my preferred way, I was integrating $w$ from $x/2$ to $x$. Easier to get right, at least for me.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: correct me if I am wrong, isn't $\int_a^b *=\int_a^c * +\int_c^b *$ "when" $a<c<b$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas You're right! I am getting $\frac{3}{8}$ as answer!

Comment: @TheDoctor:  The solution of Aditya Agarwal is essentially right, minor numerical glitch.

Comment: @JessePFrancis, yes it is. So using $0<\frac x2<x$, $$\int^x_0 *=\int^{\frac x2}_0 *+\int^{x}_{\frac x2} *$$ and thus, $$\int^x_0 *-\int^{\frac x2}_0*=\int^{x}_{\frac x2}*$$

Comment: @JessePFrancis, actually I didn't think of it in these terms. I thought that the area between $\frac{x}2$ and $x$ would be equal to the area till $x$ minus the area till $\frac x2$.

Comment: Yeah, corrected the mistake. @AndréNicolas, btw what is $w$ in "integrating from $\frac x2$ to $x$"?

Comment: I guess it should have been $t$, the function we are integrating is $t+O(t^2)$, so the integral from $x/2$ to $x$ is $(1/2)(x^2-(x/2)^2)+(x-x/2)O(x^2)$, Divide by $\sin^2 x$, or $x^2$, and let $x\to 0$.

Comment: Hmm, what is $O(x)$?

Comment: I have seen it being used in series expansions.