# Limit, integral and L'Hospitals $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt$

Tags: integration, limits

> $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt$

**Question 1**: Is $\int_a^b *=\int_a^c * + \int_c^b *$ "only when" $a<c<b$?

If not, **question 2**: Where am I going wrong in using L'Hopitals rule here (as I learned [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466632/limit-of-function-involving-integrals)) to obtain

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\left[\int_0^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt-\int_0^{x}e^{-t^2}dt\right]$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-4x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{1}=0 (\ne1, \text{ the real answer})$$

And **question 3**: how to calculate the above limit correctly, since the above (what I have tried) is not working?

Comment: Hint: chain rule on the $\int_{0}^{2x}e^{-t^{2}} dt$ term.

Comment: @AlexWertheim, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your integration is incorrect - the anti-derivative of $e^{-t^2}$ with respect to $t$ is **not** simply $e^{-t^2}$ because of the chain rule.

I don't know how familiar you are with analysis, but one can show this pretty painlessly using a formal epsilon-delta style proof. Indeed, fixing $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $\delta > 0$ such that $|e^{-t^2} - 1| < \varepsilon$ when $ |t| < \delta$. Then, for $0<|x|< \delta/2$, we have

$$\left| \frac{1}{x} \int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2} \, dt - 1\right| \leq \frac{1}{x} \int_x^{2x} \left|e^{-t^2} - 1 \right| \, dt $$

$$< \frac{1}{x} \int_x^{2x} \varepsilon = \varepsilon.$$

And hence the integral goes to $1$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Analysis, yes, I am familiar with! And marking this as the answer, since it does more justice (analytic/pure) to the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 1: yes.

Question 2, using [Leibnitz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(2x)\times e^{-t^2}\Big|_{t=2x}-\frac{d}{dx}(x)\times e^{-t^2}\Big|_{t=x}}{1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\times e^{-4x^2}-1\times e^{-x^2}}{1}\\
&=1\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\, dt.$ Then

$$(1/x)\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}\, dt = (F(2x) - F(x))/x = F'(c_x) = e^{-c_x^2},$$

where we've used the FTC and the MVT. As $x\to 0, c_x \to 0,$ hence $e^{-c_x^2} \to 1.$ The limit is therefore $1.$

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hospital rule, consider $\frac u v$ with $$u=\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt$$ $$v=x$$The fundamental theorem of calculus tell that if $$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, dt$$ then $$f(x)=f\big(b(x)\big) \,b'(x)-f\big(a(x)\big)\, a'(x)$$ Applying to your case, we then have $$u'=2 e^{-4x^2}-e^{-x^2}$$ for which the limit is $1$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the $f(x)=f(b(x))b′(x)−f(a(x))a′(x)$ part of it!

Comment: You are very welcome ! This is just the generalization of the FTC since $\int_a^b f(t) dt=\int_0^b f(t) dt-\int_0^a f(t) dt$